# Visual Studio Express 2010 C++ Disassembly Debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, assembly, directx

I have a C++ program that crashes on an access violation when I run it in the Debugger with Visual Studio.  The problem is that in the past it normally would take me to a line where this happens, but for this problem it says there is no source available and takes me to the disassembly.  I have no idea how to decipher it and get any useful information.  It takes me to the following line:

```
0000000057A93F0F  cmp         dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0
```

Then if I run it again it will stop at:

```
0000000058673F0F  cmp         dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0
```

Then if I run it again it stops at the first one and then again the second one if I re-run it... it just keeps going in this loop.  I find it strange that this happens at different addresses alternating times but then again I don't even know if that is for sure the address.

How can I use this information to find the problem?

(I would post code but I have no real idea what section is causing the problem so don't know what to post... I should not that I am trying to compile [flash-to-directx](http://code.google.com/p/flash-to-directx/) with an x64 platform).

Thanks

***EDIT***

Here are the lines before the crash happens:

```
0000000057A93EF3  test        dl,1  
0000000057A93EF6  je          0000000057A93EFD  
0000000057A93EF8  call        0000000057FC8024  
0000000057A93EFD  mov         rax,rbx  
0000000057A93F00  add         rsp,20h  
0000000057A93F04  pop         rbx  
0000000057A93F05  ret  
0000000057A93F06  int         3  
0000000057A93F07  int         3  
0000000057A93F08  sub         rsp,28h  
0000000057A93F0C  mov         ecx,r8d
```

and then the crash happens at:

```
0000000057A93F0F  cmp         dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0
```

Also the last item on my call stack is:

```
Flash64_11_1_102.ocx!0000000058673f0f()
```

Comment: It crashes on attempt to read from `[rcx+11BCh]`. Now if this is call to a C++ class member function, `RCX` should contain **this** pointer and you are trying to access something within a class instance. The thing to start with is to see what is `RCX` at this point.

Comment: So when I run it and it stops if I hover over `RCX` it shows a value of `4278034432`. What is this value?  How do I figure out what that value is?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would help to show the 7 or 8 lines before the crash line as well.  That way we can perhaps determine if rcx was handed garbage from somewhere else.

Comment: Michael I edited my post above with the lines directly before the crash too.  Thanks.

Comment: `4278034432` = `0xFEFDA000` memory address. `0xFEFDA000` + `0x11BC` = `0xFEFDB1BC`. Examine what you have at those addresses.

Comment: What is the best way to check and see what is at those addresses?  Do I just add them to a watch? Or add a breakpoint for those addresses?  Sorry I'm a bit new to using visual studio for debugging... Thanks!

Comment: I noticed that in the diassembly there is just `???` at 0xFEFDB1BC... this probably isn't good?  at the rcx location it also just has `???` ... What do these mean?

Comment: Put a break point just before the line that crashes: `0000000057A93F0C  mov         ecx,r8d` here. And when you reach break point you should be able to do Watch or something similar - I'm not sure how to do it in VS (maybe, dump memory or something). It also looks like it's just a start of a function `sub rsp,28h` is setting stack frame. You can try and see what's caller sets `RCX` to if you can trace it back (just do "step-in" in debugger near offending call).

Comment: Another thing. Since you don't get any symbols resolved in debugger, this must be a call to some 3rd party library function, not Windows or your own code. Is that some library call to something that is not part of Windows `dll`'s, `msvcrtXXX.dll` or your own code?

Comment: hmmm... when i set a break point at the locations before it, when i start my program it says that it is unable to set those break points because it will not be able to hit those break points.  So how is it never going through those locations but hitting the one under it?  Does it jump from somewhere else? If it does how do I figure out where?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7647/discussion-between-azza-and-m-laing)

Comment: I'm trying to use the flash ocx (like this.. [flash-to-directx](http://code.google.com/p/flash-to-directx/) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic 64-bit pointer truncation in Adobe Flash dll. Probably some function receives `DWORD userData` instead of `void* userData` through some structure and then casts it to object pointer. This works ok in 32-bit environment, but crashes in 64-bit.

#### Explanation

```
mov         ecx,r8d
```

First operation copies only low 32-bits from `R8D` to `ECX` (ECX is 32-bit).

```
cmp         dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0
```

Second operation accesses 64-bit register, where low 32-bits contains correct address and high 32-bits contains some junk. Leading to crash, of course.

#### How to fix

This is pretty easy, if you don't mind editing dll using hex editor. You will need an old school MASM.exe (you can get one from Microsoft web-site).

Create .asm file, or get one from examples and modify, with code like this:

```
nop
nop
nop

mov ecx,r8d
cmp dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0

nop
nop
nop

mov rcx,r8d   // I've replaced ecx with rcx here
cmp dword ptr [rcx+11BCh],0
```

Create .obj file by submitting this to MASM. Open resulting file with any hex editor and notice sequence `90 90 90 first_sequence_of_bytes 90 90 90 second_sequence_of_bytes`. All you need to do is to find in original dll first sequence of bytes and replace it with second sequence of bytes. I'm pretty sure difference will be only in first byte.

This will fix your crash.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not at all familar with Assembly language... What exactly should my .asm file look like?  I tried a few different things but keep getting error like "undefined symbol rcx".  I'm pretty sure I'm not doing something right.

Comment: I finally got it to compile and build my test.obj... But now I am having trouble finding the sequence in the flash ocx.  I've looked in the flash ocx and the flash dll. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to search in ActiveX version of Adobe Flash dll. This one is installed when you are using Internet Explorer (or just use `Other operating system or browser` button on Adobe site).
Also, remember about shadowing on 64-bit Windows systems. It's not that easy to get to 64-bit dll. I've used Total Commander to access it.

Comment: Yea thanks I finally got to it.  That was the real problem... Windows was messing with me and it was hard to get to the actual 64 bit one.  I eventually just copied and pasted it into a different directory from DOS and then modified that one and load it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what features Express has, but if it lets you look at registers, I will bet that **rcx** is zero (a NULL pointer). You should also be able to look at the call stack. If so, you may find your code on the stack and you may be able to see which function is passing a NULL pointer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to look at the registers exactly.  When it breaks, I can see that `rcx` has a value of `4278034432` but I'm not sure what that means.  Is that the register?  Also, the last thing in my callstack when it breaks is `> Flash64_11_1_102.ocx!0000000058673f0f()`.  Does this mean that it is a function within the ocx that is the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, rcx is the register. Since it is not zero, it may either be from an uninitialized variable or freed memory. Try to look at the Call Stack. On regular VisualStudio it is opened by Debug->Windows->Call Stack.

Comment: I found that the last item on my call stack is `Flash64_11_1_102.ocx!0000000058673f0f()`.  Which leads me to believe something is going wrong within the flash ocx.  I should mention that this problem is only occuring during a 64-bit build.  With 32-bit there is no problem.  Maybe Flash64*.ocx is not 64-bit despite the 64 in its name?  I think it is though because flash works fine in my 64-bit browser.

Answer (score 0):

For these kinds of problems, the first thing I do is get as far along as I can in whatever steps are necessary to reproduce the problem. Once i'm as close as possible, I turn on all exception handling (ctrl+alt+e, tick all the checkboxes in the dialog that comes up), and reproduce the crash. you should break into the spot in your code where the first chance exception is unhandled and it should give you at least a little bit of context of what is causing the dump.